# How could I make a form processor?

Tags: php, forms, process, host

This may be almost impossible, but I was wondering if it's possible to make my own form processor with PHP, CGI, etc.  If I had an easily editable template I might be able to do it.  Do you know of any way I could make and host one myself?

Comment: Yes, PHP can be used to process forms. That's pretty much what it was originally was designed for. You should explain what the objective of your "form proccesor" is. Or do you have a specific coding problem? Otherwise this question is too broad and [answered in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php).

Comment: As mario said, form processing was the one of the original reasons to create PHP.

Comment: @mario:  I want it to email the form results to me just like other forms do.

Comment: You can use the `mail()` function. For file uploads (**which you should have mentioned in your original question**) you should use a mail class that simplifies that: switftmailer

Comment: @mario: do I need to upload the PHP in order for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible! Check http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Would that email the form to me?

Comment: Hm. what do you mean? you can always use `mail()` in PHP.

Comment: You should check Google Docs Forms. Then your results are organized int a spreadsheet.